# It seems jQuery .load() is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a table consists of three columns :

```
id
author
message
```

Once the user clicks on the `More` Button the button passes  the `Count`  parameter  to `.load` function. And then new data should display but it
 displays a blank page.What am i doing wrong?

this is index.php:

```
<div id="comments">
        <?php 
        $v=$db->prepare('select * from  comments limit 2');
        $v->execute();
        $data=$v->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            echo "<div>".$row['author']."</div>";
            echo "<div>".$row['message']."</div>";
            echo "</br>";
        }
        ?>
</div>
    <input type="submit" name="" id="submit" value="More">
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var commentCount=2;
        $('#submit').click(function(){
            commentCount=commentCount+2;
            $('#comments').load('loadComments.php',{count:commentCount});
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is loadComments.php:

```
<?php 
$db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax',"root","");
$newCount=$_POST['count'];

$ex=$db->prepare('select * from comments limit $newCount');
$ex->execute();
$data=$ex->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "<div>".$row['author']."</div>";
    echo "<div>".$row['message']."</div>";
    echo "</br>";
}

?>
```

EDİT:

If I use this way everything is ok.

```
$v=$db->prepare('select * from  comments limit 3');
```

But I have checked `count` parametre inside loadComment.php

```
echo $newCount;
```

and I am able to get the value Its funny

Comment: Have you included `jQuery.js` file ?

Comment: Yes sir I have included

Comment: You need to check console. May some errors will give clue. next step could be commend all jquery code and then uncomment line by line and add alert message. It will help to debug that on which line exact error is

Comment: It should be `fetchAll` , not `fetchALL` in you loadComments.php  [ref](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Try using a double-quoted string...."select.....$newCount"

Comment: yes you are right but nothing changed

Comment: @mrunion  It works !!! But I dont understand I  mostly use  single -quoted and interestingly if I use  single -quoted  'fetchALL' doesnt work if I use double-quoted '  It works both   'fetchALL'  and  'fetchAll'  Can you please explain sir

Comment: single quotes return the string as it is but when you use double codes then any variable which is inside that string will be replaced with its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of using Single quoted strings (as `'`) instead of Double quote strings (as `"`) - as @mrunion mention in the comments

In PHP when using `'` the inner string is not being evaluate in contrast to the `"` mark. So the statement of `'select * from comments limit $newCount'` is been sent as is and the `$newCount` is not been evaluate as 2 or what ever int it hold.

Full explanation about PHP quote can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)